# Formatting a Measure in SSAS cube

Tags: ssas, cube, number-formatting

I have a measure that show number in millions / billions.

The formatting of the number for now is like this : "$#,##0.0;-$#,##0.0"

I would like to format the number to show something like this:

If the Orginal number is: 117,100,000 $

I want to see it like that: 117.1 M $.

Can we do it on SSAS cube?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this format string:

```
0,,.0 \M $
```

This trick is a bit buried in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).